# Tailing log until certain time threshold is reached

Tags: linux, shell, ksh, sh

I'm tailing a log like this:

```
while [[ ! -n "${ready}" ]]; do
    start_info=`grep "Ready" $LOG_FILE`
    sleep 10
done
```

If the log file doesn't have "Ready" inside this goes on forever, how can I make it run for lets say 200 seconds? Like some kind of time threshold.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `while [[ -z "${start_info}" ]]; do` ?

Comment: @khachik yes I found your example and modified

Comment: main problem here is that you "grep" the entire file every time. if the log file is huge, you might run into a perf issue.

Comment: @Yuval What else are you recommending?

Comment: tail -F $LOG_FILE | grep "Ready" > tmp.file, and run your script on the tmp file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question correctly (`while [[ ! -n "${ready}" ]]; do` is confusing) here is an example how you can check time threshold:

```
#!/bin/sh

...
timelimit=200
pausetime=10

while [[ -z "${start_info}" ]]; do
  start_info=`grep "Ready" $LOG_FILE`
  sleep $pausetime
  timelimit=$((timelimit - $pausetime))
  if [ $timelimit -le 0 ]; then
    break
  fi  
done
```

Comment: For consistency, why don't you use `[[]]` in both places (or `(( timelimit <= 0 ))` in the second) and `$()` instead of backticks? You can also do `(( timelimit -= pausetime ))` (note that you have a typo where it says "limit=" it should say "timelimit="). It's not necessary to quote and use curly braces on the variable in the double brackets, you can do `[[ -z $start_info ]]`. As is, it's like wearing a belt and suspenders with coveralls.

Answer (score 3):

This avoids repeatedly grepping the whole file:

```
start=$SECONDS
limit=200
while read -r line
do
    if [[ $line =~ $ready ]]
    then
        start_info=$line
        break
    fi
    if (( $SECONDS >= start + limit ))
    then
        break
    fi
done < "$LOG_FILE"
```

Comment: I think this answer is better than mine. +1

Comment: but if you don't grep the whole file, what if at the time of greping the line you are way pass server has started?

Comment: @London: The `while read` loop starts at the beginning of the file and reads each line. The problem with my answer is that it doesn't hold the file open so it ends as soon as it reaches the end of the file without waiting for additional lines to be added. I think something based on Yuval's comment regarding `tail -f` would be better. Look through [these questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Btail+%2Bkill) to see if you find something useful.